# Recuperar snapshot dentro de um nó

Tags: android, firebase, android-adapter, firebase-database

Eu preciso recuperar todos os usuarios dentro de um nó usuario, segue estrutura do firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para eu recuperar esses valores estou fazendo um addListenerForSingleValueEvent, segue código:

```
    private DatabaseReference firebaseRef;
    private DataSnapshot usuariosSnapshot;

firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();

                //recuperar usuarios para criação do feed na hora da postagem
                DatabaseReference usuariosRef = firebaseRef
                        .child("usuarios");
                usuariosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        usuariosSnapshot = dataSnapshot;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                postagemPendente.salvar(usuariosSnapshot);
```

mesmo a referencia estar apontando pro lugar certo o usuariosSnapshot ainda mostra como nulo, o que preciso fazer parar pegar todos esses valores de dentro do nó usuários?

Obs: Isso tudo dentro de um Adapter, o que acho irrelevante mas por via das duvidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente no lugar de `DatabaseReference usuariosRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios");` acrescentar `.getReference().`

O getReference() obtém o nó raiz do banco de dados. Mais informações [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=pt-br).

Assim ficaria `DatabaseReference usuariosRef = firebaseRef.getReference().child("usuarios");`

Comment: "firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();"nessa linha eu já configuro o getReference